# python classes. unsure if I am linking functions correctly. program not printing when I ask

Tags: python, class

the code below is part of a bigger set of code. You will see that I have some test commands below the code. I am testing to make sure all the methods in the class work. My problem is that the code isnt printing where told. Anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong. Are the methods properly linked to the class?

thank you

```
   class Score:
# class to hold a running score, from object to parameter
# also to set number of scores that contribute to total of 1

    def __init__(self):
#initalizes the running score and score input accumilators
        self.runScore = 0
        self.scoreInputs = 0

    def updateOne (self, amount):
#updates running score by amount and Score input by 1
        self.runScore += amount
        self.scoreInputs += 1

    def updateMany(self,lst):
#updates running score by the sum of the list and score inputs by the amount of
# items in the list
        self.runScore += sum(lst)
        self.scoreInputs += len(lst)

    def get(self):
#returns the current score based on total amount scored
        return self.runScore
        print(score.runScore)

    def average(self):
        aver = self.runScore // self.scoreInputs
#returns the average of the scores that have contributed to the total socre
        return aver
        print(score.aver)


    agame = Score()
    agame.updateOne(4)
    agame.updateOne(2)
    agame.updateMany([3,5,4,2,8])
    agame.get()
    agame.average()
```

**my output**

```
>>> 
>>>
```

as you can see nothing prints

**update**

so I removed the return statements and fixed some other bugs, now I have an error which leads me to think I have not fully connected the methods to the class. But I am still figuring it out. Any ideas?

```
    class Score:
# class to hold a running score, from object to parameter
# also to set number of scores that contribute to total of 1

    def __init__(self):
#initalizes the running score and score input accumilators
        self.runScore = 0
        self.scoreInputs = 0

    def updateOne (self, amount):
#updates running score by amount and Score input by 1
        self.runScore += amount
        self.scoreInputs += 1

    def updateMany(self,lst):
#updates running score by the sum of the list and score inputs by the amount of
# items in the list
        self.runScore += sum(lst)
        self.scoreInputs += len(lst)

    def get(self):
#returns the current score based on total amount scored
        #return self.runScore #debug test possible removal
        print(Score.runScore)

    def average(self):
        aver = self.runScore // self.scoreInputs
#returns the average of the scores that have contributed to the total socre
        #return aver #debug test possible removal
        print(Score.aver)


agame = Score()
agame.updateOne(4)
agame.updateOne(2)
agame.updateMany([3,5,4,2,8])
agame.get()
agame.average()
```

**Output**
I have an error that reads:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\christopher\Desktop\hw2.py", line 37, in <module>
    agame.get()
  File "C:\Users\christopher\Desktop\hw2.py", line 24, in get
    print(Score.runScore)
AttributeError: type object 'Score' has no attribute 'runScore'
```

Comment: in `get(self)` you return befor print. Same in `average(self)`.

Answer (score 1):

The print statements have to go before the return statement. Once you return, the program is out of that function.

Answer (score 1):

A `return` statement is like a `break`; after it returns the desired variable, it exits the aforementioned function.

```
def foo():
    return 'bar'
    print 'foobar'
```

---

```
>>> foo()
'bar'
```

Thus, you need to move your `print`s before the `return`s:

```
class Score:

# class to hold a running score, from object to parameter
# also to set number of scores that contribute to total of 1

def __init__(self):
#initalizes the running score and score input accumilators

    self.runScore = 0
    self.scoreInputs = 0

def updateOne (self, amount):
#updates running score by amount and Score input by 1

    self.runScore += amount
    self.scoreInputs += 1

def updateMany(self,lst):
#updates running score by the sum of the list and score inputs by the amount of
# items in the list

    self.runScore += sum(lst)
    self.scoreInputs += len(lst)

def get(self):
#returns the current score based on total amount scored


    print(score.runScore)
    return self.runScore

def average(self):
    aver = self.runScore // self.scoreInputs
#returns the average of the scores that have contributed to the total socre


    print(score.aver)
    return aver


agame = Score()
agame.updateOne(4)
agame.updateOne(2)
agame.updateMany([3,5,4,2,8])
agame.get()
agame.average()
```

Comment: Thank you @A.J. I have fixed the return statements. I seem to be having an issue of the methods being fully connected to the class. Am I correct? Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong? currently researching the problem myself

Comment: @ChristopherJakob i'll just begin to look in to that :)

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `return` leaves the current function call and return a value.
See the [Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#return)

So, u should complete all your operations before return of a function, same as C.

Answer (score 0):

so ultimatly it came down to not using return statements but print statements. 
And also linking the methods with  self.(xxx) rather than Score.

All is resolved. Thank you all